# How to prove the equivalence of two definitions of the local Lipschitz condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition, lipschitz-functions

Here's one definition, from *A Short Course in Ordinary Differential Equations*, Qingkai Kong (2014):

[def1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj0ID.png)

Here's another definition from *Ordinary Differential Equations*, Jack K. Hale (1980):

[def2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8qIn.png)

Denote the first definition by $(1)$, and the second by $(2)$.
It is obvious that $(2)\implies (1)$, because if the Lipschitz condition is satisfied on any closed bounded subset of $D$, then it must be satified on a closed neighborhood of any given point in $D$ (does it require some extra assumptions about $D$ for any point to have a closed neighborhood?). But it isn't obvious to me why $(1)\implies (2)$.
How to prove that these two definitions are equivalent?

---

**EDIT:**
It seems that I can't have embedded images in my post yet, so here's the two definitions mentioned above (I changed the notation to make it more consistent):

Let $f:D\subset \mathbb R\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$. $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $x$ on $D$, if

**Definition (1)**
For any $(t^*,x^*)\in D$, there is a neighborhood $\mathcal N^*$ of $(t^*,x^*)$ and a constant $k>0$ such that $$|f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)|\leq        k\lvert x_1-x_2\rvert,\ \forall(t,x_1),(t,x_2)\in\mathcal N^*\cap D.$$

**Definition (2)**
For any closed bounded set $U\subseteq D$ there is a $k>0$ such that $$|f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)|\leq k|x_1-x_2|,\ \forall(t,x_1),(t,x_2)\in U.$$

Comment: Note that closed bounded subsets are (relative) compact.